# Options to hide reputation information on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, reputation

Is there a way to view the site without having to look at reputation information?

I do not want to track my rep information or see anyone else's.  I think that'll let me focus more on the questions themselves.  Is anyone else interested in this feature?

I don't see anything on Stack Overflow itself, but are there any add-ins or [Greasemonkey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greasemonkey) scripts that do this?

Comment: Closely related: [Hide the rep and badge count on a user's info box on answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/21458)

Comment: slightly related: [Would a user capping their own reputation at 99k have any user experience downsides?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345482/303080)

Answer (score 8):

I guess the best you can do is get [Sampson](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/130154/jonathan-sampson) to write or write yourself a Greasemonkey script.

The main cause of SO's addictiveness is rep and competition over it, so I doubt they'll willingly waste effort in offering an option to hide it.

Answer (score 6):

For anyone still looking for a way to hide the reputation from (almost) all Stack Exchange Network (including Stack Overflow).

I have created [a JavaScript script on GitHub](https://gist.github.com/oussamabadr/39bfc2fdb814d9eb1afd60a92b5f1fe4) for the [Tampermonkey extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo) using Chrome, but it should work as well for other browsers.

Here is a script (if GitHub is down for some reason):

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Hide Reputation
// @namespace    https://gist.github.com/
// @version      0.1
// @description  Hide Stack Exchange user reputation.
// @author       oussama.badr
// @match        https://stackoverflow.com/*
// @match        https://*.stackexchange.com/*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';

    var allRepDivs = document.getElementsByClassName("-flair");
    for (var i = 0; i < allRepDivs.length; i++) {
        allRepDivs[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
})();
```

Answer (score 3):

You could add something like this to a browser extension  (in this case Chrome):

```js
else if (/^https:\/\/meta.stackexchange.com\/.*/.exec(url))
    style = ".reputation-score { display: none; }"
```

Or if you don't want to know anything about the person:

```css
style = ".user-details { display: none; }"
```

Answer (score 3):

It's not an option for the entire network, but IMHO worth mentioning: MathOverflow just implemented this by default: [Reputation and badges are no longer visible next to the users' names](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/5209/70594), with a (currently broken) option to opt out. Who knows, it might evolve to a (hopefully opt-*in*) feature on other sites in the network.

Comment: Now in addition to the bug report linked in your post, they have also added an official announcement from the moderators: [Viewing reputation and badges is now opt-in](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/5218).

Answer (score 2):

While really far from a full solution, at least you can hide your own reputation from the top bar if you keep your window narrow enough:

[image]

See how a wider window instead shows your own reputation:

[image]

Mind that there is however a site counterquirk by which your own reputation will still suddenly appear if changed, even using the narrow view originally not showing reputation:

[image]

Once reloading the page or loading another site's page, your own reputation will be hidden again [at the top bar].

Answer (score -3):

Reputation is one of the metrics I use to determine the value of the answer or question. With this I mean I am more likely to vote someone up with more reputation, and also more likely to answer their question. Ignoring the gaming this is one of the most important metrics I use when determining how or where value is added in a particular tag/question. Hiding it defeats that object for me.

Comment: This is bad, IMO. It allows users who reach some critical mass to gain upvotes simply on past merit.

Comment: @Yuck If there answer is correct and they already have a reputation, why shouldn't they?

Comment: It results in accelerating returns. I've seen good answers from users with less than 1K rep receiving little attention in favor of users with less complete - though still valid - answers. It's clearly a psychological result of those voting. This isn't a complain per se. Just an observation.