# How to disable/remove all badges and reputation?

Tags: feature-request, reputation, badges, notifications

Is there any setting/userscript/extension available to disable/remove all reputation, badges and badge notifications from the stackoverflow interface?

It just clutters the interface for me and I don't see the point in having them.

Activity on sites like stackoverflow as someone that answers questions should be purely altruistic anyway ;)

In addition to the greasemonkey script mentioned in the answers I'm also using this userscript in Opera

```
if(/(stackoverflow|superuser|serverfault)\.com$/.test(location.hostname)){
    opera.addEventListener('BeforeScript', function(e){
        var o = document.getElementById('notify-container')
        if(o){
            o.style.display = 'none';
            removeEventListener.call(opera, 'BeforeScript', arguments.callee, false);
        }
    }, false);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30489)'s a greasemonkey script that does that

And the accepted answer to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11586) also has one (although it only hides reputation)

Comment: Perfect, that was exactly what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 3):

There's no way to do this in the UI; you'd have to write a greasemonkey script to do it. Wouldn't be very hard, as all the `<div>`s and `<span>`s you'd want to hide have unique names.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use [site-specific stylesheets](http://www.google.com/search?q=site+specific+user+stylesheet). It'd be even easier if SO provided a [CSS signature](http://archivist.incutio.com/viewlist/css-discuss/13291).