# Implement a CSS signature

Tags: feature-request, design

Change from `<body>` to `<body id="stackoverflow-family-website">`.

This way we can restyle the website simply modifying our user stylesheets without the need for greasemonkey scripts or similar.

For example:

```
#stackoverflow-family-website .reputation-score
{
   font-color: red; // Reputation is now shown in red
}
```

<sup>Idea taken from [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40777/how-to-disable-remove-all-badges-and-reputation/40793#40793)</sup>

Comment: ... or write a greasemoney script to add the ID to the body tag and bobs you're uncle!

Comment: Write a greasemonkey script to get around writing a greasemonkey script?

Comment: Pretty much, yeah

Comment: +1 except I think it should be a CSS class name, not an ID.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using a Gecko based browser? Use this instead:

```
@-moz-document domain(stackoverflow.com) {
 .reputation_score { font-color: red; }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Every system that exists, be it built into the browser or a plugin, that allows you to change the style of visited pages already has a way to discriminate websites.

Why would you want to add an `id` to the body?

Even if you were using a bookmarklet (the lowest tech I can think right that would allow you to change a website's layout) can check the current address (`javascript:alert(location.host);return false;`).