# Allow user to customize (or even suppress) reputation indicator

Tags: feature-request, achievements-dialog

Currently, users with an account get informed of upvotes to their answers via a small green rectangle reporting the number of such upvotes in the topbar. Clicking on it displays a pop-up window with links to the upvoted answers. The only way I know of to clear the upvote indicator is to click on it.

This makes for an interface which forces certain moves on the user.

Could there be a configuration in the user profile to allow the user to completely suppress this indicator of reputation points upvotes?

Also the pop-up window would serve rather to indicate which questions (among those to which the user contributed either by asking or by answering or possibly commenting) received new activity: activity such as an edit of the question, or a new answer, or an edit to an old answer, or perhaps even new comments to the question or the answers.

The reported information would become completely independent of the upvotes.

The user would go click there only as way to keep track of changes to what he/she contributed to.

The only testimony to reputation points changes would be in the total reputation points the user sees underneath his/her account name. Next time I will ask a way to suppress that too ;-)

---

As per request in comments:

- The benefit to the user was already clearly expressed above: stop being *forced* to be informed of upvotes.
- The benefit to the site would be to create a more adult and saner relationship with its contributors.

Also moved from comments:

The upvote indicator could display the green rectangle only on hover event.

Comment: The missing bit from your post: what's the benefit here to the site and to users?

Comment: @Oded I think 'One doesn't get distracted by the  gaming aspect of the sites so can focus instead on the business: helping people'

Comment: @Oded as an intermediate possibility: display the green indicator only on hover events. Thus, _if_ the user wants to check upvotes it is possible as currently. But there would not be anymore permanent green rectangle which one is _forced_ to click upon.

Comment: Again: what's the benefit to the site and users? (please **edit** the question to provide missing details - comments are for clarification and should be deleted once they have accomplished their task).

Comment: So your contention is that informing people of votes is childish and insane? Do you have anything to qualify that?

Comment: @Clive Perhaps you will have something to qualify _why_ you feel so much antagonized by my post.

Comment: I agree with Clive that this sentence could use some clarification: "the benefit to the site would be to create a more adult and saner relationship with its contributors" How exactly does removing the reputation notification achieve that?

Comment: @PatrickHofman hard to tell without having tried it. I am asking for the user to be able to obtain this via customization of preferences.

Comment: Eh? Did you _want_ me to feel antagonised? I didn't, sorry. I wanted to know what you meant by that bizarre statement, and whether you had anything to back it up. From the clumsy deflection in your response, I assume you don't have anything. I'll ask again though, this time maybe try to answer the question: do you have anything to back up those unsubtle claims, or are they just nonsense?

Comment: @Clive but on which basis do you attribute me some « non sensical claims » ? No a native English speaker but childish isn't the direct opposite of adult, and insane isn't of sane. Things are more subtle. You dislike my post, avoid inuendos like "clumsy", "nonsense", "I'll ask again though", "anything to back it up" "unsubtle claims". That would definitely make for adult discourse, thanks.

Comment: There's that word "adult" again, it does seem you're trying to wind people up. No matter, it's not likely to work. And your refusal to address my point speaks volumes about the validity of yours. One last try, with no extra wording that you can pretend is stopping you from addressing it this time: why is what we currently have not "adult", what parts of what we have would be "saner", and why do they need to be? Go.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure this is something many would like to implement. Besides any arguments against, if it is an issue for you, you can hide the achievements dropdown completely by adding a user style to your browser (if you don't know how, type "[Your browser] user stylesheet" or something similar in to your prefered search engine). This should do it:

```
.topbar .icon-achievements { display: none }
```

Which results in this:

> [image]

You still recieve other notifications through the inbox, you simply don't see any reputation gains (or losses) or badges earned.

If you still want the notifications but don't want the distracting green background, simply change the color like so:

```
.topbar .icon-achievements .unread-count { background: #2d2e2f; }
```

> [image]

Comment: If I get it right it means that it would not need zillions of dollars to implement this as a user preference. That's good to know.

Comment: I only needed  (for Firefox, in `/chrome/userContent.css`) to insert the `!important` keyword in your css snippet: `display: none !important;` . It works indeed !

Comment: @jfbu glad you got it sorted :)

Comment: I have completed your advice into an even more radical setting at http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/6957/4686. This seems to achieve without JS something in the spirit of the question http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40777/how-to-disable-remove-all-badges-and-reputation. I am not sure about badge notifications because I forgot if they get signalled via the inbox dropdown or the reputation dropdown.

Answer (score 4):

I disagree with this sentence of yours:

> the benefit to the site would be to create a more adult and saner relationship with its contributors

If indeed the removal of the reputation notification does make users more sane, that it should be removed for everyone, not just those users not interested in reputation. Those users only here to farm reputation are not going to disable the notification and thus will never get 'saner' as you say, and those only interested in helping don't care for the reputation, whether you show it or not.

And also this doesn't seem a real argument:

> the benefit to the user was already clearly expressed above: stop being forced to be informed of upvotes.

You are not really forced to be informed. If you don't care, just don't look there.

Comment: "If you don't care, just don't look there". I would be glad to hear some psychologist opinion here about how that applies to a green rectangle on top of black bar.

Comment: So go do a study. Get some evidence that it's any sort of problem, and present it. Things are not so because you say or suggest they are, proof is required.

Comment: @Clive. It definitely _is a problem to me_. And, except if I am the truly amazing isolated guy, probably to a few others. My post has asked for a preference setting. You seem to imply that on the basis of nothing I am asking for a non-wanted overhaul of a design. Such emotional resistance is truly amazing. There _is_ a design goal in the green rectangle. Obtaining from the site designers to make this design goal explicit would be a desirable outcome of this unwelcomed conversation.

Comment: Can you stop trying to pretend this is about "emotions"? You already jumped on my first comment as you felt you had "antagonised" me - you have not. People are asking you why your feature request would be a good thing, and you're refusing to answer them. If nothing else it's just rude.

Comment: There is no point in going on like this. You again say I refuse to answer, but there is nothing to answer additionally to what I have already said. I will repeat for the last time: 1) I am asking a preference setting. 2) if day after day you again and again _have_ to click on some indicator, you are made psychologically dependent upon that indicator. 3) there is currently no other choice. It is like being exposed to permanent unwanted advertisement. It is _not_ neutral. It has consequences.

Comment: And those consequences are what, specifically? You are asking for a new feature, which takes time and money to implement, the burden is on you to make a case for that money being spent. So far you're not, you've just said it's "psychologically" bad. Bad **how**? And please include your references

Comment: @Clive The consequences are that on connecting to the site the first thing 99% of people will do is to go click there if there is the green thing. It means that before connecting to the site, the mindset is about "what have been my recent achievements". I have articulated enough. Are you a site designer or moderator here ? then I can quit this meta site -- or just a regular user -- then what are your credentials to oppose me in such way in comments without providing an answer of your own ?

Comment: It doesn't matter what my position or credentials are. What matters is that for a feature request to be accepted, you need to provide some sort of reasoning behind it, some hint as to why it would be a good thing to spend development time on. Your comments indicate you think you've articulated that well: you haven't, yet. You've used obviously charged words like "adult" and "saner", and have steadfastly refused to explain what you mean by those, and why you chose to use them in the first place. Try to look at this from a neutral's point of view. What you're asking doesn't make a lot of sense

Answer (score 3):

Your question is full of assumptions that don't hold for all users of the site. One is that the green rectangle is used as a signal of rep change. Perhaps you think that's a tautology. But for me, when I see and click that rectangle, I am not thinking "oooh I wonder which pieces of my work have earned me more lovely lovely rep." You see, I have observed over time that old answers and questions earn rep if they are bumped to the front page by activity such as another answer or an edit. Often, I enjoy reading these other answers. The green rectangle for me is a signpost that perhaps something of mine has been bumped, and there may be content I would enjoy reading as a result.

This signposting could, in theory, be folded into the red notifications (another answer has been added to something you answered, a question you answered has been edited, etc) but I find the green rectangle a surprisingly useful route to the same information.

Yes, some days all it says is "that thing you wrote an hour ago was helpful to someone" - but I feel no lack of adultness or sanity in liking the occasional "thankyou" for my work. If you do, I suggest visiting the site less often, and choosing times when your mood is more resilient to such motivators.

On the matter of "forcing" moves, the profile indicates rep gain and is clickable, yet I somehow resist the urge to click it:

[image]

So also consider just paying no attention to the green rectangle if it holds nothing of value for you.