# The rich get richer phenomenon in stackexchange communities

Tags: feature-request, reputation, voting

I've noticed that when two or more answers are provided to a question, people's votes tend to gravitate toward the answer posted by the person with higher reputation. I've observed this "rich get richer" phenomenon in nearly every community I am a part of. This even happens in cases where the lower reputation user posts their answer long before the higher reputation user comes along.

I feel like this unnaturally causes people to flock toward one idea/answer, discounting the opinions/views of people with lower reputation.

I understand how reputation is meant to signal one's knowledge of the subject area and the site in general; however, I think these reputation effects prevent people from judging the correctness of the answers themselves.

I would like to hear other's opinions on this. One suggestion I have is to hide the answerer's identity and reputation score for the first 24 hours after a question is asked. I think this would go a long way to resolving this issue.

**Edits:**

- Supporting evidence:

  - [Should reputation be hidden until an answer is accepted?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79621/should-reputation-be-hidden-until-an-answer-is-accepted)
  - [Is it OK that on StackOverflow, the rich are always getting richer?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254049/is-it-ok-that-on-stackoverflow-the-rich-are-always-getting-richer)
  - [Rich get richer phenomenon on CV](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4583/rich-get-richer-phenomenon-on-cv)
- The fact that this is [evidently a polarizing topic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ECNq3.png) deserves discussion in itself.
- The post linked by rene is certainly relevant: [Should reputation be hidden until an answer is accepted?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79621/should-reputation-be-hidden-until-an-answer-is-accepted) however, it was posted nearly 9 years ago (is there no statute of limitations on posts marked as duplicate?). I'm sure it is no longer in anyone's mind, perhaps it deserves to be revisited? It seems I have caused a sufficient amount of controversy to prevent that objective from being met here, though.

Comment: linking to examples of this phenomenon would improve your case. Statistical evidence even more so. As is, you're just asserting that this happens with no supporting evidence whatsoever.

Comment: @DavisBroda It is through observation, I'm wondering if others have observed the same thing. As for statistical analysis, I doubt this is reasonable as it would require evaluating if the "correctness" of the answer aligns with the score, which is quite subjective.

Comment: If your aim is to have better votes on posts, write that feature request. If you spin this around *the rich get richer* off course you polarized it ...

Comment: I think newer users might vote more on the bases of higher rep == better answer, but what you'll see from other users with a high rep is that they'll hold other high reps user's feet to the fire. Answers that could get new user upvotes might not for higher rep users.\

Comment: Note that the conversation on CV which you link to includes answers with pretty compelling arguments that this is not a thing.

Answer (score 17):

This isn't quite true. There is indeed a bias in how people tend to vote but it's based on "who posted the answer first". It's known as the "Fastest Gun in the West Problem" and you can read more about that here: [Fastest Gun in the West Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/9731/400547)

Also, another thing that might come into play is that people who have written a lot of answers know how to write answers that are more likely to be upvoted. So, the more experience someone as, the more easily they will gain reputation. Which is, when you think about it, quite logical.

Comment: The way you've answered suggests you feel it's either one or the other.
I would posit that both problems could exist, though "Fastest Gun in the West Problem" seems like a bigger issue.

*(And, I believe there are plenty of other reputation related issues not encompassed by either problem description)